# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'coolwarm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, attributeerror

I am newly learning matplotlib. I have plotted some data in a surface plot. But without colors it looks monotonous. I have referred this matplotlib [example document](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html) and used the same code for plotting. I am getting the above mentioned error in this line

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

I have tried upgrading the matplotlib module and still getting the same error. Could anyone help me in fixing this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do all of [the other colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) work in your environment or is this a general colormap problem? And please always post the full traceback of an error message. I assume you haven't changed the example code.

Comment: I'm guessing you did `import matplotlib as cm` instead of `from matplotlib import cm`.

Comment: yes, i did the same @user2357112. Thank you guys.